# Which has greater bandwidth a STP or a coaxial?

Tags: cable

I googled and found diffrent results to what data I had about them,have a look:
http://www.adiwebs.com/comparison-utp-twisted-pair-coaxial-cable-and-fiber-optic/
But the bandwidth of these two cables are diffrent according to my data:

```
STP     16 mbps
Coaxial 10 mbps
```

Please can anyone varify the real bandwidths..Thanks

Comment: That is a terrible, terrible article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual bandwidths are much, much higher than that, potentially in the range of gigabits per second. The thing of it is that you need an adapter capable of handling the speed as well as cable of sufficient quality.

Comment: So why do they post such articles?

Comment: Because then the site will show up on search engines for more terms.

Comment: Bandwidth is measured in Hz, not bit per second. You are confusing this with bit-rate or throughput! I am assuming the bandwidth of the coaxial is much higher than that of the average twisted pair cable. However the Ethernet standard is faster over twisted pair since Ethernet over coaxial is legacy. But compare this with throughput over DOCSIS and you will be surprised. Twisted pair has more pairs usually, while coax usually has only one.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you're talking about the medium (coax vs. twisted pair) or the typical interface card using that medium.  Typical small coax interface cards of several years back were 10 megabits/sec, using BNC connectors on RG-58 coax.  Typical twisted pair interface cards (of today) are capable of 10/100/1000 megabits/sec depending on the quality of the cable.  In terms of timeline, coax came first and then twisted pair.  At one time the interface cards available were roughly equal in bandwidth at 10 Mbps.   The 16 Mbps you see was (probably) for a different technology (not ethernet based) known as Token-Ring, sponsored by IBM.  Token Ring was initially 4 Mbps but eventually an upgrade to 16 was developed. T-R ran over STP (Shielded Twisted Pair) as opposed to TP.  Eventually token ring pretty much died out due to the significantly increased cost of the STP installation and the significantly greater price of the interface cards which ran $150 at a time when you could get a twisted pair ethernet for $50.

If you're talking strictly about how fast you can push bits thru the media then Ignacio is right, both are capable of gigabit speeds. Note that both have substantial limits in terms of the max distance they can go at super high speed.  If you really want maximum speed and distance - you want fiber optics.

Answer (score 1):

Even Wikipedia is better than that site that you found, which as Ignacio stated is absolutely horrible:

Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)#Internet_connection_bandwidths

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths#Local_area_networks

> 56 kbit/s     Modem / Dialup
>
> 1.5 Mbit/s    ADSL Lite
>
> 1.544 Mbit/s  T1/DS1
>
> 10 Mbit/s     Ethernet
>
> 11 Mbit/s     Wireless 802.11b
>
> 44.736 Mbit/s     T3/DS3
>
> 54 Mbit/s     Wireless 802.11g
>
> 100 Mbit/s    Fast Ethernet
>
> 155 Mbit/s    OC3
>
> 300 Mbit/s    Wireless 802.11n
>
> 622 Mbit/s    OC12
>
> 1 Gbit/s  Gigabit Ethernet
>
> 2.5 Gbit/s    OC48
>
> 9.6 Gbit/s    OC192
>
> 10 Gbit/s     10 Gigabit Ethernet
>
> 100 Gbit/s    100 Gigabit Ethernet

Bandwidth typically is determines by what kind of signals, cable quality and all sorts of other factors.  Old style CoAx cable was typically around the 10MBps, while UTP/STP has speeds of 10Mbps, 100Mbps, 1Gbps and above (see the "Ethernet" entries above).  Fibre typically has a higher bandwidth than copper but it is highly dependant on the technology of the fibre and trancievers.

Any good networking book should give you an overview of the technologies involved in the different types of cable.